# How to add a Lens Flare effect in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This code displays a circle: I want to add a lens flare (halo effect as in PhotoShop) over this. How to do it ?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'pink';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#f0505f';
context.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A lens flare effect overlays many smaller effects on top of your image to create the lens flare.**

[image]

**Here's a tutorial of which effects you will need for your lens-flare effect:**

http://library.creativecow.net/articles/mylenium/lens_flare.php

**And here's the html5 canvas techniques needed to create each effect.**

I've been wanting to do a lens flare effect, but haven't had time to accomplish it.

So give it a go...if you have difficulties just post a question and I'd be glad to help.

Good luck with your project!

**These are radial gradient fills (with & without a blur)**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- createRadialGradient
- shadowBlur

[image][image]

**These are stars (thick and thin) with radial gradient fills & blur**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- star path created with a regular polygon
- createRadialGradient
- shadowBlur

[image][image]

**This is a radial gradient fill with a blur that has been "flattened" using Y-scaling**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- createRadialGradient
- shadowBlur
- scale transform (scaling Y will "flatten" the circle into a sliver)

[image]

**This is an arc**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- arc path command

[image]

**This is an arc with a gradient that runs with the stroke**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- arc path command
- image slicing (example: [Gradient Stroke Along Curve in Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027087/gradient-stroke-along-curve-in-canvas/24029653#24029653))

[image]

**This is a series of rectangles drawn along a circle**

Html5 canvas techniques needed:

- fillRect
- trigonometry (calculate x/y points along a circle)
- trigonometry (extend the radius of a circle)

[image]